# POI cannot open workbook to open .xls files and eclipse throw an exception

Tags: java, database, eclipse, excel, apache-poi

When I try to open a .xlsx file in POI, I get an exception:

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The supplied POIFSFileSystem does not contain a BIFF8      'Workbook' entry. Is it really an excel file? 
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getWorkbookDirEntryName(HSSFWorkbook.java:223)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:245)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:188)
        at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:170)

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(fileName));

                            POIFSFileSystem file = new POIFSFileSystem( input );
                            //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xls file
                            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

                            //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
                            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

                        //Iterate through each rows one by one
                        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
```

just trying to read the data that .xls file contain but cannot open it !

Comment: Where in the code are you getting this exception? Please paste the code snippets too

Comment: Check the file. It seems that it is not really an excel file. May be of any other format but just extension has been changed. Please check it whether it is opening in excel, and if yes, then use Save As option and save it in a .xls file format and try again. If issue still persists, share the code with us.

Comment: its excel file , and i save the file as .xls but eclipse still throw aexception

Answer (score 5):

Don't create an `HSSFWorkbook` on a `.xlsx` file.  An `HSSFWorkbook` represents an `.xls` file, and an `XSSFWorkbook` represents an `.xlsx` file.

In fact, usually your code doesn't even need to know which it's working with.  Create your `Workbook` with `WorkbookFactory`, as this example from [the Busy Developer's Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream) shows:

```
// Use a file
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("MyExcel.xls"));

// Use an InputStream, needs more memory
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("MyExcel.xlsx"));
```

If you must, you can create an `XSSFWorkbook` directly:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);  // You can use a FileInputStream
```

or with an `OPCPackage`.

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(myInputStream);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
```